# Generate Bitmask

Tags: c++, c++11, bitmask, bit-manipulation

Given two integers; `size` and `offset`, how would I go about generating a bitmask with the following properties;

```
MSD             LSD
1111 1111 0000 1111
          ^  ^
size = 4 -|  |
             |  
offset = 4  -|
```

Comment: Doesn't `((1 << size) - 1) << offset` produce the complement of what you want? Also, it'd be undefined behavior to use that with `size=32` and `offset=0` (assuming 32-bit int)

Comment: It does, but then it's a matter of simply doing the complement to get the real thing. And my sized will never be the full thing, there's a static_assert for that (now that is).

Comment: @markgz: The reason I marked the question C++11 is not due to relatedness, but rather due to the fact that I'm willing to use C++11.

Comment: Please don't add solutions to the question. If you have a solution, feel free to post an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the question is tagged as c++, I'm going to provide an STL based solution:

```
bitset<NUM_BITS> bs(0);
bs = ((bs.flip() << size).flip() << offset).flip();
```

Same code split into several lines:

```
bitset<NUM_BITS> bs(0);
bs.flip();
bs <<= size;
bs.flip();
bs <<= offset;
bs.flip();
```

Performance considerations are up to the readers.